# Finding whether an extension is normal

Tags: group-extensions, normal-extension

I have $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt5)$ and I think I found the base for the extension on $\mathbb Q$ as ${ a+b\sqrt5 +ci + di\sqrt5 ; a,b,c,d\in \mathbb Q}$

But I don't know at which polynomial to look in order to see if it is normal or not.

Comment: This is a biquadratic extension ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biquadratic_field)), thus it is normal. Indeed, it's the splitting field of $$(x^2+1)(x^2-5)$$ It was easy, wasn't it?

Comment: The polynom to look the roots is simply multyplying the ones that generate each separatedly?

Comment: If you want the polynomial to be irreducible (even this is not necessary), consider the minimal polynomial of $i+ \sqrt{5}$ (which is a unique generator of this extension): $$(x-i-\sqrt5)(x-i+\sqrt5)(x+i-\sqrt5)(x+i+\sqrt5)=x^4-8x^2+36$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A field extension is said to be normal, if the minimal polynomial of every element of the larger field, splits completely within the field itself.

However, there are some other conditions, as it turns out, for a finite field extension to be normal.

In particular, finite field extensions which are splitting fields of *separable polynomials* (*not irreducible, but separable*) are normal as well as separable (it goes the other way also). One either defines Galois extensions to have this property, or there is a separate definition, which is shown to be equivalent to normal,separable.

---

It turns out that $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt 5)$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $(x^2+1)(x^2 - 5)$. Why? Because the field contains each of the roots of the polynomial, and it is easy to see that any other field with this property contains $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt 5)$ by definition of $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt 5)$ being the smallest field containing $i$ and $\sqrt 5$.

Note that $(x^2 + 1)(x^2 - 5)$ is separable as all its roots are of multiplicity one. Of course, the extension is finite, of degree four.

---

Thus, $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt 5)$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb Q$. It is, infact, a Galois extension, with Galois group $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: Thanks, i hadn't been introduced to this definition, only the one that states that irreductible polynoms that have one root, have everyone

Comment: You are welcome! This criteria is easy to spot and comfortable to use. Note that if the field extension is normal but not separable, then you will have to find minimal polynomials  of the extension elements separately and show that they split.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find the minimal polynomials of $i$ and $\sqrt(5)$. The product of these certainly contains $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{5})$ inside its decomposition field.

Comment: But im getting confused cause shouldnt the minimal be irreductible

Comment: what do you mean by monomic?

Comment: Mistook, i meant irreductible

Comment: what is your definitino of normal field extension?

Comment: That if a root belongs to the extension then all roots do

Comment: But when i look at simple extension i look at the minimal polynom, and this one is irreductible